# im getting 404 api not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Im using mailgun to send email yet I am getting 404(not found) error.
Here is my work

Client side

```
this.state= {
   message: "main message",
}

handeSendRequest(){
  await fetch('/api/eMail', {method:'post', headers: {'Content-type' : 'application/json' }}, body: JSON.stringify(this.state)){
}

}
render(){
  return(
    <Button onClick={this.handeSendRequest} > Send it </Button>
   )

 }
```

emailRouter.js

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')(configuration);

router.post('/api/eMail', async (req,res) => {
    try {

        let message = req.body.message;
      sendEmail(message,function (err) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }else{
                        console.log("Sent email");
                    }

                });

 res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            msg: 'Success'
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            msg: err
        });
    }
});


function mail(message, callback){

  const mail = `<p>{message}</p>`;

    var mail = mailcomposer({
        from: 'from@email.com',
        to: "to@email.com",
        subject: "subject",
        html: mail
    });
    mail.build(function(mailBuildError, message) {

        var dataToSend = {
            to: to@email.com,
            message: message.toString('ascii')
        };

        mailgun.messages().sendMime(dataToSend, function (sendError, body) {
            if (sendError) {
                console.log(sendError);
            }
            callback(sendError);

        });
    });
}
```

Server.js

```
const app = express();

const emailUtil = require('./emailRouter.js');

app.use('/api/eMail', emailUtil);
```

Not sure why but I'm getting these error `http://localhost:3000/api/eMail 404 (Not Found)`. Looks like the client side is right but the backend for some reason not getting the call. How can I modify my work so that the email can successfully be sent.

Comment: You're not using async / await correctly in the client or the server... I would suggest looking up the proper way of using it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what if you just register like this : `app.use(emailUtil);`
 cause, you register both the /api/eMail, in your server.js, and in your emailRouter.js

Then I think, express want you to request on /api/eMail/api/eMail

Comment: Hi, Christophe mentions /api/eMail/api/eMail.  e.g. http://localhost:3000/api/eMail/api/eMail.  Your server file says bind the routes in emailUtil to /api/eMail/ and in the emailRouter.js file, you have /api/eMail/, therefore /api/eMail/api/eMail.  If you edit the line in server file to be app.use('/', emailUtil);, you then should be able to hit http://localhost:3000/api/eMail/